# Getting URL of the resource in Xcode Playground is inconsistent between Xcode versions

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcode12

I've got a simple Xcode playground where I read swift file and do some more stuff with it. The problem is that on Xcode 12 I get nil when I try to read file with "swift" extension (other files work well). It used to work on Xcode 11. Is there a new way to do it? It's a macOS playground.

[image]

Code:

```
["json", "txt", "swift"]
    .forEach { print(Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: $0, subdirectory: nil)) }
```

**Xcode 12**:

```
Optional([api.json -- file:///var/folders/x5/wg_gx53z0254lpyfmm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/B11DE6A8-7AXB-4E08-8987-3F8178CC6BB3/])
Optional([text.txt -- file:///var/folders/x5/wg_gx53z0254lpyfmm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/B11DE6A8-7AXB-4E08-8987-3F8178CC6BB3/])
Optional([]) // .swift file
```

**Xcode 11.6**:

```
Optional([api.json -- file:///var/folders/x5/wg_gx53z0254lpyfmm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/FDC17DB1-5C7D-4412-8CE5-ABA9A7A3C913/])
Optional([text.txt -- file:///var/folders/x5/wg_gx53z0254lpyfmm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/FDC17DB1-5C7D-4412-8CE5-ABA9A7A3C913/])
Optional([code.swift -- file:///var/folders/x5/wg_gx53z0254lpyfmm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/FDC17DB1-5C7D-4412-8CE5-ABA9A7A3C913/])
```

Comment: Just a guess: it makes no sense to include a code file as a resource, so maybe the playground compensates.

Comment: @matt maybe it doesn't but I wonder why it worked in Xcode 11.6 and doesn't in Xcode 12.

Comment: I am suggesting that it should never have worked and they fixed the bug.

Comment: I'm having this same problem trying to load a .metal file from Resources. If I change it to .txt it works.